# Asset is not present in asset pipeline after deploy to heroku with webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack

I am using rails 5.2.3

Locally I can download the pdf but on **Heroku** it through an error 500.

Error is: *ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "pdf.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.):*

Here are my heroku logs

```
2019-06-12T20:26:05.707039+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-06-12T20:26:05.706962 #4]  INFO -- : [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0]   Rendered clients/orders/show.pdf.erb within layouts/clients/application.pdf.erb (38.4ms)
2019-06-12T20:26:05.709399+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-06-12T20:26:05.709314 #4]  INFO -- : [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 55ms (ActiveRecord: 16.2ms)
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710722+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-06-12T20:26:05.710296 #4] FATAL -- : [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0]
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710724+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-06-12T20:26:05.710384 #4] FATAL -- : [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "pdf.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710726+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-06-12T20:26:05.710579 #4] FATAL -- : [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0]     1: <html lang="fr">
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710728+00:00 app[web.1]: [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0]     2: <head>
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710732+00:00 app[web.1]: [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0]     3:   <meta charset="utf-8" />
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710733+00:00 app[web.1]: [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0]     4:   <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'pdf' %>
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710734+00:00 app[web.1]: [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0]     5: </head>
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710736+00:00 app[web.1]: [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0]     6: <body>
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710737+00:00 app[web.1]: [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0]     7:   <div>
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710739+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-06-12T20:26:05.710659 #4] FATAL -- : [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0]
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710815+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-06-12T20:26:05.710734 #4] FATAL -- : [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0] app/views/layouts/clients/application.pdf.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_clients_application_pdf_erb___1711932080367152756_47199839415040'
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710823+00:00 app[web.1]: [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0] app/controllers/clients/orders_controller.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in show'
2019-06-12T20:26:05.710825+00:00 app[web.1]: [b789ac1d-fe64-434c-b259-a2f3949a7bd0] app/controllers/clients/orders_controller.rb:16:in `show'
```

In my `views/layouts` I have `application.pdf.erb`

```html
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'pdf' %>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The pdf file is stored like so `vendor/assets/stylesheets/pdf.scss`
, in vendor I also have a customized bootstrap file `bootstrap.min.css`

**pdf.scss**

```css
@import "bootstrap.min";

.someclass {}
```

In  `config/initializers/assets.rb`I have this line:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( pdf.scss, chartkick.js)
```

I am also using webpacker and that maybe here the problem...

here is my **webpacker.yml**

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .jsx
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default
  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false
  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

In **public/assets** file (locally) and on heroku there is no trace of the pdf file....

What Am I missing here?

I can forward more code, just let me know... I really hope you could help me.

### EDIT

Here is my package.json 
I moved webpack-cli but it still doesn't work :( 
I deployed again, Am I supposed to run a new command to make this working ?

```
{
  "name": "kamelot",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "flatpickr": "^4.5.7",
    "highcharts": "^7.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-color": "^2.17.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react_ujs": "^2.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but there is a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1561) with Webpacker v4 in which `webpack-cli` is marked as a `devDependency` in `package.json` configuration file.

When deploy task runs `webpacker:compile` and there is no `webpack-cli`, there is no error thrown, so the deploy finish but no file is compiled in `public/packs` folder.

To fix this, you should simple move the `webpack-cli` dependency outside of `devDependencies` to `dependencies`.

**UPDATE**

If you are using `capistrano` to deploy your project, you should add `public/packs` and `node_modules` (the last is optional) to your `linked_dirs` in `deploy.rb` configuration file:

Also if you use node_modules, you must run `yarm:install` before precompile your assets. To do that, simply add this task in your `deploy.rb` file:

```
before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:yarn_install"
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Run rake yarn install"
  task :yarn_install do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
       execute("cd #{release_path} && yarn install --silent --no-progress --no-audit --no-optional")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For more details on this, check [webpacker documentation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/deployment.md#capistrano) for capistrano deployment.

**UPDATE 2**

This is another long shot, but there is a [reported issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1164) in which the order of `heroku` buildpacks can affect assets compilation process. `node` buildpack must come first, and then `ruby` buildpack. The following should fix the issue:

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby
```

Another quick fix suggested in the same issue is to run `rake webpacker:compile` inside `heroku` console, but this doesn't fix deploy assets compilation problem.

Comment: I added my package.json and moved the webpack-cli, nothing change :(

Comment: Maybe it is because of your `capistrano` configuration. I updated my answer so you can check it out.

Comment: I don't use Capistrano... When I deploy I use git push heroku master...
What should I do?

Comment: @johan I made another update to my answer. Hope this one helps you.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it doesn't make the job :( 
The `vendor` folder is not compiled at all, nor locally nor on heroku

Comment: the problem was in assets.rb, vendor folder was not loaded I added this `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << Proc.new { |path, fn| fn =~ /vendor\/assets\/stylesheets/ }`