# Assets in vendor are not compiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

In my Rails 5.2.3 app I have a specific layout for a pdf which is stored in `vendor/assets/stylesheets`

In **production.rb**

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

In **assets.rb** I have:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(pdf.scss, chartkick.js)
```

After running locally `rails assets:precompile` in my  **public/assets** folder I have a finger print of my assets including `chartkick-xxxxxxxxx.js` but not a trace of `pdf-xxxxxx.scss` nor in `sprokets-manifest-xxxxx.json`

My pdf download works locally, but not on heroku... I suppose it's because of the compilation...

I already did all the suggestions from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56570204/8919469)

Maybe my webpacker.yml is not set correctly ?

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .jsx
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3000
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default
  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false
  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line in assets.rb made the job

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << Proc.new { |path, fn| fn =~ /vendor\/assets\/stylesheets/ }
```